# How to transpose/pivot data in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I know there's no direct way to transpose data in hive. I followed this question: [Is there a way to transpose data in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624991/is-there-a-way-to-transpose-data-in-hive) , but as there is no final answer there, could not get all the way.

This is the table I have:

```
 | ID   |   Code   |  Proc1   |   Proc2 | 
 | 1    |    A     |   p      |   e     | 
 | 2    |    B     |   q      |   f     |
 | 3    |    B     |   p      |   f     |
 | 3    |    B     |   q      |   h     |
 | 3    |    B     |   r      |   j     |
 | 3    |    C     |   t      |   k     |
```

Here Proc1 can have any number of values. ID, Code & Proc1 together form a unique key for this table. I want to Pivot/ transpose this table so that each unique value in Proc1 becomes a new column, and corresponding value from Proc2 is the value in that column for the corresponding row. In essense, I'm trying to get something like:

```
 | ID   |   Code   |  p   |   q |  r  |   t |
 | 1    |    A     |   e  |     |     |     |
 | 2    |    B     |      |   f |     |     |
 | 3    |    B     |   f  |   h |  j  |     |
 | 3    |    C     |      |     |     |  k  |
```

In the new transformed table, ID and code are the only primary key. From the ticket I mentioned above, I could get this far using the to_map UDAF. (Disclaimer - this may not be a step in the right direction, but just mentioning here, if it is)

```
 | ID   |   Code   |  Map_Aggregation   | 
 | 1    |    A     |   {p:e}            |
 | 2    |    B     |   {q:f}            |
 | 3    |    B     |   {p:f, q:h, r:j } |  
 | 3    |    C     |   {t:k}            |
```

But don't know how to get from this step to the pivot/transposed table I want.
Any help on how to proceed will be great!
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up using:

```
add jar brickhouse-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

select 
    id, 
    code,
    group_map['p'] as p,
    group_map['q'] as q,
    group_map['r'] as r,
    group_map['t'] as t
    from ( select
        id, code,
        collect(proc1,proc2) as group_map 
        from test_sample 
        group by id, code
    ) gm;
```

The to_map UDF was used from the brickhouse repo: https://github.com/klout/brickhouse

Comment: I dont see to_map UDF in brickhouse repo. Could you please some more details around this ?

Comment: here is what i was looking at https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/resources/brickhouse.hql

Comment: You can use "collect" UDAF - which is similar to to_map
The link: https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CollectUDAF.java
You should replace "to_map" with "collect"
I've updated the solution with the same.

Comment: Hi! I am trying to something similar. In your answer, you have group_map['p'] etc, indicating that you know the values ahead of time. How did you solve for not knowing what the values in Proc1 were? Please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Here is the approach i used to solved this problem using hive's internal UDF function, "map":

```
select
    b.id,
    b.code,
    concat_ws('',b.p) as p,
    concat_ws('',b.q) as q,
    concat_ws('',b.r) as r,
    concat_ws('',b.t) as t
from 
    (
        select id, code,
        collect_list(a.group_map['p']) as p,
        collect_list(a.group_map['q']) as q,
        collect_list(a.group_map['r']) as r,
        collect_list(a.group_map['t']) as t
        from (
            select
              id,
              code,
              map(proc1,proc2) as group_map 
            from 
              test_sample
        ) a
        group by
            a.id,
            a.code
    ) b;
```

"concat_ws" and "map" are hive udf and "collect_list" is a hive udaf.

Comment: can you explain how you would do it when the value is of numeric format. I saw your blog but the code doesn't match up with the table. http://hadoopmania.blogspot.com/2015/12/transposepivot-table-in-hive.html

Comment: Does this example generalize to cases where you have more than one column to pivot on?

Comment: Does this generalizes to cases where you might have values besides 'p','q','r','t'?

Answer (score 7):

Yet another solution.

**Pivot** using [Hivemall](https://github.com/myui/hivemall) `to_map` function.

```
SELECT
  uid,
  kv['c1'] AS c1,
  kv['c2'] AS c2,
  kv['c3'] AS c3
FROM (
  SELECT uid, to_map(key, value) kv
  FROM vtable
  GROUP BY uid
) t
```

`uid  c1  c2  c3
101  11  12  13
102  21  22  23`

**Unpivot**

```
SELECT t1.uid, t2.key, t2.value
FROM htable t1
LATERAL VIEW explode (map(
  'c1', c1,
  'c2', c2,
  'c3', c3
)) t2 as key, value
```

`uid  key  value
101   c1     11
101   c2     12
101   c3     13
102   c1     21
102   c2     22
102   c3     23`

Answer (score 1):

I have not written this code, but I think you can use some of the UDFs provided by klouts brickhouse: https://github.com/klout/brickhouse

Specifically, you could do something like use their collect as mentioned here: http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/use-collect-to-avoid-the-self-join/

and then explode the arrays (they will be of differing length) using the methods detailed in this post http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/exploding-multiple-arrays-at-the-same-time-with-numeric_ra

Comment: Thanks for the note. I don't need the collect UDAF, as its the same as the Map Aggregation UDAF I'm already using here. I could do the same by using the key names in my map Aggregation as new columns, The real issue is I want it to be dynamic - ie - I do not know how many different "Proc1" values I might end up with, and I want to dynamically create more columns for each new "Proc1"

Answer (score 1):

1. I have created one dummy table called hive using below query-

`create table hive (id Int,Code String, Proc1 String, Proc2 String);`

2. Loaded all the data in the table-

```
insert into hive values('1','A','p','e');
insert into hive values('2','B','q','f'); 
insert into hive values('3','B','p','f');
insert into hive values('3','B','q','h');
insert into hive values('3','B','r','j');
insert into hive values('3','C','t','k');
```

3. Now use the below query to achieve the output.

```
select id,code,
     case when collect_list(p)[0] is null then '' else collect_list(p)[0] end as p,
     case when collect_list(q)[0] is null then '' else collect_list(q)[0] end as q,
     case when collect_list(r)[0] is null then '' else collect_list(r)[0] end as r,
     case when collect_list(t)[0] is null then '' else collect_list(t)[0] end as t
     from(
            select id, code,
            case when proc1 ='p' then proc2 end as p,
            case when proc1 ='q' then proc2 end as q,
            case when proc1 ='r' then proc2 end as r,
            case when proc1 ='t' then proc2 end as t
            from hive
        ) dummy group by id,code;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of numeric value you can use below hive query:

Sample data

```
ID  cust_freq   Var1    Var2    frequency
220444  1   16443   87128   72.10140547
312554  6   984 7339    0.342452643
220444  3   6201    87128   9.258396518
220444  6   47779   87128   2.831972441
312554  1   6055    7339    82.15209213
312554  3   12868   7339    4.478333954
220444  2   6705    87128   15.80822558
312554  2   37432   7339    13.02712127

select id, sum(a.group_map[1]) as One, sum(a.group_map[2]) as Two, sum(a.group_map[3]) as Three, sum(a.group_map[6]) as Six from
( select id, 
 map(cust_freq,frequency) as group_map 
 from table
 ) a group by a.id having id in 
( '220444',
'312554');

ID  one two three   six
220444  72.10140547 15.80822558 9.258396518 2.831972441
312554  82.15209213 13.02712127 4.478333954 0.342452643

In above example I have't used any custom udf. It is only using in-built hive functions.
Note :For string value in key write the vale as sum(a.group_map['1']) as One.
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is also a way for Pivot

```
SELECT TM1_Code, Product, Size, State_code, Description
  , Promo_date
  , Price
FROM (
SELECT TM1_Code, Product, Size, State_code, Description
   , MAP('FY2018Jan', FY2018Jan, 'FY2018Feb', FY2018Feb, 'FY2018Mar', FY2018Mar, 'FY2018Apr', FY2018Apr
        ,'FY2018May', FY2018May, 'FY2018Jun', FY2018Jun, 'FY2018Jul', FY2018Jul, 'FY2018Aug', FY2018Aug
        ,'FY2018Sep', FY2018Sep, 'FY2018Oct', FY2018Oct, 'FY2018Nov', FY2018Nov, 'FY2018Dec', FY2018Dec) AS tmp_column
FROM CS_ME_Spirits_30012018) TmpTbl
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(tmp_column) exptbl AS Promo_date, Price;
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you can explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Unpivot, we can simply use below logic.

```
SELECT Cost.Code, Cost.Product, Cost.Size
, Cost.State_code, Cost.Promo_date, Cost.Cost, Sales.Price
FROM
(Select Code, Product, Size, State_code, Promo_date, Price as Cost
FROM Product
Where Description = 'Cost') Cost
JOIN
(Select Code, Product, Size, State_code, Promo_date, Price as Price
FROM Product
Where Description = 'Sales') Sales
on (Cost.Code = Sales.Code
and Cost.Promo_date = Sales.Promo_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statements and some help from collect_set to achieve this. You can check this out. You can check detail answer at - http://www.analyticshut.com/big-data/hive/pivot-rows-to-columns-in-hive/

Here is the query for reference,

```
SELECT resource_id,
CASE WHEN COLLECT_SET(quarter_1)[0] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COLLECT_SET(quarter_1)[0] END AS quarter_1_spends,
CASE WHEN COLLECT_SET(quarter_2)[0] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COLLECT_SET(quarter_2)[0] END AS quarter_2_spends,
CASE WHEN COLLECT_SET(quarter_3)[0] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COLLECT_SET(quarter_3)[0] END AS quarter_3_spends,
CASE WHEN COLLECT_SET(quarter_4)[0] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COLLECT_SET(quarter_4)[0] END AS quarter_4_spends
FROM (
SELECT resource_id,
CASE WHEN quarter='Q1' THEN amount END AS quarter_1,
CASE WHEN quarter='Q2' THEN amount END AS quarter_2,
CASE WHEN quarter='Q3' THEN amount END AS quarter_3,
CASE WHEN quarter='Q4' THEN amount END AS quarter_4
FROM billing_info)tbl1
GROUP BY resource_id;
```