# What's the beautiful way to do transpose/pivot row-to-colume in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Given following table1

```
id  category    city    value
100 A   x   10
100 A   y   20
100 B   x   1000
101 A   x   100
101 C   x   2
102 B   x   3
```

We want to transpose the values of category_city as columns, i.e.

```
id  A_x A_y B_x B_y C_x
100 10  20  1000    NULL    NULL
101 100 NULL    NULL    NULL    2
102 NULL    NULL    3   NULL    NULL
```

The "max(case when ...)" method mentioned [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392956/sql-how-to-transpose) doesn't works well. Say, even if we have only 100 distinct values of category and 10 distinct values of city, the combination of category_city will be 1000. We need to manually write 1000 lines of "case(when ...) as category_city". This is ugly.

```
SELECT t.userid
     MAX(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'Username' THEN t.fieldvalue ELSE NULL END) AS Username,
     MAX(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'Password' THEN t.fieldvalue ELSE NULL END) AS Password,
     MAX(CASE WHEN t.fieldname = 'Email Address' THEN t.fieldvalue ELSE NULL END) AS Email
FROM TABLE t 
GROUP BY t.userid
```

Any beautiful way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpose/pivot data in hive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive)

Comment: Here is a [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-transpose-data-in-Hive) post related to your question.