# Pivoting a large table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a very large table and I need to pivot it. Something similar to this: ([How to transpose/pivot data in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive#))
I need to go from here

```
 | ID   |   Code   |  cat     |   count | 
 | 1    |    A     |   p      |   e     | 
 | 2    |    B     |   q      |   f     |
 | 3    |    B     |   p      |   f     |
 | 3    |    B     |   q      |   h     |
 | 3    |    B     |   r      |   j     |
 | 3    |    C     |   t      |   k     |
```

to here:

```
 | ID   |   Code   |  p   |   q |  r  |   t |
 | 1    |    A     |   e  |     |     |     |
 | 2    |    B     |      |   f |     |     |
 | 3    |    B     |   f  |   h |  j  |     |
 | 3    |    C     |      |     |     |  k  |
```

But, the categories I have are several around (2000) and I don't want to write a separate select for each category. How could I do this?

Comment: "separate select"?

Comment: Did you consider writing code?

Comment: You should share what you have tried already

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, I did. But I didnt write distributed code as I don't know how to. Code on a single machine which tried to pivot the csv took forever to run.