# hive column to rows

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

how can I create new columns in HIVE according to the type stored in an existing column?

for example, I have :

```
id    ProductType
1       car
2       bike
3       truck
```

and I would like to have:

```
id    car    bike    truck
1      1     null    null
2     null     1     null
3     null   null      1
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

```
Use `case` statement to convert values into columns:

select id, case when ProductType = 'car' then 1 end as car,
           case when ProductType = 'bike' then 1 end as bike,
           case when ProductType = 'truck' then 1 end as truck
 from your_table;

OK
id      car     bike    truck
1       1       NULL    NULL
2       NULL    1       NULL
3       NULL    NULL    1
Time taken: 35.442 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```