# Transpose Hive SQL data from existing column

Tags: sql, hive, transpose

i'm currently using the following query to get the below results

```
select 
  mt.name,
  mt.title,
  mt.type,
  mt.day1,
  mt.day2

from mytable mt
```

gives me results like

```
name       title      type      day1              day2
batman     super      gothom    12/22/1990        2/2/1990
batman     super      dc        1/9/1990          7/5/1990
```

The new selection should create new columns based off type, and take the data from a specific column 'in this case day2' I ideally want my results to look like

```
name       title      gothom          dc      
batman     super      2/2/1990        7/5/1990
```

How can i achieve the desired table above.

Comment: and you don't want info from day1. Correct?

Comment: @Counter10000 yes correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpose/pivot data in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hive, you can pivot the data using conditional aggregation:

```
select mt.name, mt.title,
       max(case when type = 'gothom' then day2 end) as gothom,
       max(case when type = 'dc' then day2 end) as dc
from mytable mt
group by mt.name, mt.title;
```