# How to transform Table in hive

Tags: hive

I have a table in Hive in below format.

```
std_id  std_name sub_id sub_name marks 
1       xxx      123    Eng      70
1       xxx      125    Maths    90
1       xxx      124    Science  80
```

I want a table in below format as output.

```
std_id std_name Eng Science Maths  
1      xxx      70  80      90
```

how can i get the output with using Hive Query..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpose/pivot data in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX ( CASE.. )` with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT std_id
    ,std_name
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN sub_name = 'Eng'
                THEN marks
            END) AS Eng
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN sub_name = 'Science'
                THEN marks
            END) AS Science
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN sub_name = 'Maths'
                THEN marks
            END) AS Maths
FROM t
GROUP BY std_id
    ,std_name;
```