# How to go from long to wide structure in HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, reshape

I have a hive data that looks like this [data in long format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOs0d.png)

I'd like to restructure it to look like this [data in wide format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5l0d.png)

What I have looks like this [my latest attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar99f.png)

This is the code that I've used. I'd like to get rid of all the NULL's and consolidate all the months into a single row under single year.

```
select carrier, year, month,

max(case when month =1 then quantity end) as jan,
max(case when month =2 then quantity end) as feb,
max(case when month =3 then quantity end) as mar,
max(case when month =4 then quantity end) as apr,
max(case when month =5 then quantity end) as may,
max(case when month =6 then quantity end) as jun,
max(case when month =7 then quantity end) as jul,
max(case when month =8 then quantity end) as aug,
max(case when month =9 then quantity end) as sep,
max(case when month =10 then quantity end) as oct,
max(case when month =11 then quantity end) as nov,
max(case when month =12 then quantity end) as dec

from (select final_month.*, row_number() over 
(partition by carrier, year order by carrier, year) from final_month) 
final_month group by carrier, year, month;
```

Here are all the references that I've been using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive) [link](https://analyticshut.com/pivot-rows-to-columns-hive/)

Thank you!

Comment: You can also use `group_map`

Comment: Could direct me to examples of group_map use? Thanks.

Comment: http://hadoopmania.blogspot.com/2015/12/transposepivot-table-in-hive.html?m=1

Comment: I was basing my script on this one, but I couldn't really work out group_map, so it'd be great if there's step-by-step explanation somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `month` from the select and group by. And I believe you want SUM, not max(), but you know the data better of course:

```
select carrier, year, 
sum(case when month =1 then quantity end) as jan,
sum(case when month =2 then quantity end) as feb,
sum(case when month =3 then quantity end) as mar,
sum(case when month =4 then quantity end) as apr,
sum(case when month =5 then quantity end) as may,
sum(case when month =6 then quantity end) as jun,
sum(case when month =7 then quantity end) as jul,
sum(case when month =8 then quantity end) as aug,
sum(case when month =9 then quantity end) as sep,
sum(case when month =10 then quantity end) as oct,
sum(case when month =11 then quantity end) as nov,
sum(case when month =12 then quantity end) as dec
from ...
group by carrier, year
```