# How do i convert vertical rows into horizontal in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm stuck with a Hive query that involves converting the horizontal rows to vertical rows

Below is my data

```
No     FlagsName    Flag_value
--      ----        ----------
A        Flag_1        1
A        Flag_2        2  
A        Flag_3        3
B        Flag_1        4
B        Flag_2        1
B        Flag_3        6
```

After conversion , the table should be

```
No      Flag_1    Flag_2    Flag_3
---      ----      -----     -----
A         1         2         3
B         4         1         6
```

Any input on this would be helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to transpose data in Hive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624991/is-there-a-way-to-transpose-data-in-hive)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpose/pivot data in hive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive)